# Replicate data from cloud SQL postgres to bigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I am looking for the recommended way of streaming database change from cloud SQL (postgres) to bigQuery ? I am seeing that CDC streaming does not seems available for postgres, does anyone know the timeline of this feature ?

Thanks a lot for you help.

Jonathan.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries

Answer (score 1):

With Datastream for BigQuery, you can now replicate data and schema updates from operational databases directly into BigQuery.

Datastream reads and delivers every change—insert, update, and delete—from your MySQL, PostgreSQL, AlloyDB, and Oracle databases into BigQuery with minimal latency. The source database can be hosted on-premises, on Google Cloud services such as Cloud SQL or Bare Metal Solution for Oracle, or anywhere else on any cloud.

https://cloud.google.com/datastream-for-bigquery

https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/quickstart-replication-to-bigquery

**CloudSql -> GCS -> BigQuery**

https://cloud.google.com/architecture/performing-etl-from-relational-database-into-bigquery

**Cloud Data Fusion**

https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/sqlserver-to-bigquery

**Cloud SQL federated queries**

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries

**SQL Server to BigQuery using Dataflow**

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/sqlserver-to-bigquery

**BigQuery subscriptions**

If no transformation is needed

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery

Comment: SANN3 this solution you mentioned is still in preview mode.

Answer (score 0):

> **You have to create an ETL process. That will allow you to automatically transform data from Postgres into BigQuery. You can do that using many ways, but I will point you to the two main approaches that I've already implemented:**

**Way 1:**
***Set Up the ETL Process manually:***

Create your ETL using open source tools...
This method involves the use of the COPY command to migrate data from PostgreSQL tables and standard file-system files. It can be used as a normal SQL statement with SQL functions or PL/pgSQL procedures which gives a lot of flexibility to extract data as a full dump or incrementally. You need to know that it is a time-consuming process and would need you to invest in engineering bandwidth!
Also, you could try different tech stacks to implement the above, and I recommended this one [Java Spring Data Flow](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-data-flow-etl)

**Way 2:**
***Using DataFlow***

You can automate the ETL process using GCP's [DataFlow](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/performing-etl-from-relational-database-into-bigquery) without coding your own solution. It is faster and it cost, of course.

> DataFlow is Unified stream and batch data processing that's
> serverless, fast, and cost-effective.

Check more details and learn in a minute [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow)
Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45630225/etl-on-google-cloud-dataflow-vs-spring-batch-bigquery)

Comment: Thanks @ddeveloperr! I have also came across to scheduled query as very quick way of incrementally update my BQ table!